# How to assign javascript array as jinja variable?

Tags: javascript, flask, error-handling, jinja2

I am trying to  assign javascript array as jinja variable but it throws error

[this is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZtcW.png)

[Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8mkM.png)

- i want the data to be taken as a array

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect both code and error message to be in the **question post** as **text**, not *linked* as *image*. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass your list to the template. You can do without the conversion to JSON here.

```py
return render_template('game.html', game=game, board=board)
```

To then use this variable in javascript, you can use the Jinja2 filter [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson). The result is your list as an array.

```js
window.onload = start({{ board | tojson }});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used json.dumps before but normally I can grab my variables I send in my render_template using this syntax.

```
var board_arr = $("#board").val();
window.onload = start(board_arr);
```